# How to build query from other queries

Tags: mysql, drupal, join, subquery

I want to create a query that will list all users and their profile information, however the profile info has to be gotten using a rather complex procedure.

```
SELECT options.`value` FROM users
RIGHT JOIN profile on(profile.uid = users.uid)
RIGHT JOIN field_data_field_ethnicity on(field_data_field_ethnicity.entity_id = profile.pid)
RIGHT JOIN options on(field_data_field_city.field_ethnicity_value = bdc_options.`index` AND bdc_options.`key` = "ethnicity")
WHERE users.uid = 1 #needs to go through all users in table
ORDER BY field_data_field_ethnicity.revision_id DESC
LIMIT 1

SELECT options.`value` FROM users
RIGHT JOIN profile on(profile.uid = users.uid)
RIGHT JOIN field_data_field_city on(field_data_field_city.entity_id = profile.pid)
RIGHT JOIN options on(field_data_field_city.field_city_value = bdc_options.`index` AND bdc_options.`key` = "city")
WHERE users.uid = 1
ORDER BY field_data_field_ethnicity.revision_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Just going from these two fields, how would I go through the users table and get something like

```
USER  |  CITY   |  ETHNICITY  
  1   |  London |   Koalabear         
  2   |  Paris  |   Fiddle
```

Here are the tables in question: http://pastebin.com/feNvzMZw

The field table has all the entries with a entity_id that refers to the profile table and a revision id which refers to the revision number.. I always need the highest to be up to date

Comment: Please add some table aliases to your query so we know what's coming from where. And/or include your table DDL.

Comment: `field_data_field_ethnicity`? Ouch...

Comment: I put the table names for all the variables.  Ethnicity is strange for me to see as well, but at least this is a pretty complete survey (not just the 2 fields at all)

Comment: I've added the table schema in a pastebin.. all the field_data-Field tables have identical structure